# Unable to install R package library(psych)

Tags: r, windows, psych

library(psych)
Error in library(psych) : there is no package called ‘psych’
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

> install.packages("psych", dependencies = FALSE)
> Warning in install.packages :
> unable to access index for repository https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib:
> cannot open URL 'https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘psych’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.4:
cannot open URL 'https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES'

> 

Please, what can I do to get this resolved? thank you.

Comment: First, download and install [Rtools34.exe](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html), not forgetting to update the Windows PATH system variable to include the directory of Rtools34.exe. Then `remotes::install_version("psych", version = "1.8.3.3", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/")`.

Comment: Greetings from SO! The way this is currently written is a bit confusing. It sounds like you tried to install the package but there was some issue on your end with how it was being installed. I would reformat this question and provide more detail about the commands you gave. It seems like a basic question but it's difficult to understand the way it is currently written.

Comment: Could be that your version of R needs updating. You are now on 3.4, and the current version is 4.2. If you can install it, installr::updater() will update R. You can also go to https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/ and download the installer.

Comment: I tried to install the R package psych with R 4.2.1 and it worked very well :)